# Can’t pass data correctly to modal presentation using ForEach and CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

Im trying to pass data of some object from list of objects to modal sheet, fetching data from CoreData.

The problem is that no matter what object I click on in the list, only the data form last added object appears in the details view.

The same goes for deleting the object - no matter what object I'm trying to delete, the last one is deleted all the time.

Problem disappears using NavigationLink, but it is not suitable for me.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CarScrollView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Cars.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var cars: FetchedResults<Cars>

    @State var showDetails = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach (cars, id: \.self) { car in

                    Text("\(car.text!)")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.showDetails.toggle()
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetails) { CarDetail(id: car.id, text: car.text)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There should be only one sheet in view stack, so just move it out of `ForEach`, like below

```
struct CarScrollView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Cars.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var cars: FetchedResults<Cars>

    @State private var selectedCar: Car? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView (.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach (cars, id: \.self) { car in

                    Text("\(car.text!)")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.selectedCar = car
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: self.$selectedCar) { car in
             CarDetail(id: car.id, text: car.text)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Asperi! However it gives me an error "Instance method 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that 'Cars' conform to 'Identifiable'". Any thoughts how to fix this?

Comment: @anton, just add empty `extension Car: Identifiable {}`, because Car already has id.

Comment: What if I want to pass a binding to CarDetail?