# SwiftUI: How to connect currentPage of PageView with firing view's passing index

Tags: uikit, swiftui, uipageviewcontroller

I follow Apple's example [interfacing-with-uikit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) to use PageView in SwiftUI. And I want to implement it in my app. The scenario is that in `MovieView`, when the user taps an image of image list then it triggers call to `PageView` with views and selected index as parameters.

But when I click on any item of image list, it always show the page view with the 1st element. I try to change it in `init()` of `PageView`, however it is not working.

In console, I try to print something, and I see the currentPage is not changed.

```
ReceivedIdx: 0
Current page: 1
ReceivedIdx: 3
Current page: 1
ReceivedIdx: 5
Current page: 1
```

Currently, `currentPage` is connected between `PageView` & `PageViewCollection`, but how to connect `selectedIdx` with them? Because it is the trigger point for which image is selected.

### MovieView

```
...
private struct ImageList: View {
    var images: [ImageViewModel]
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var selectedIdx = 0

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Images")
                .font(.headline)
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 6) {
                    ForEach(0..<images.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        KFImage(source: .network(self.images[i].fileURL))
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 200)
                            .aspectRatio(1.77, contentMode: .fit)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedIdx = i
                                self.showSheet.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    PageView(self.images.map { PresentedImageView(image: $0) }, selectedIdx: self.selectedIdx)
                }
            }.frame(height: 120)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal).padding(.bottom)
    }
}

private struct PresentedImageView: View {
    var image: ImageViewModel

    var body: some View {
        KFImage(source: .network(image.fileURL))
        .resizable()
        //.frame(width: gr.size.width - 6, alignment: .center)
        .aspectRatio(1.77, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
...
```

### PageView

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageView<Page: View>: View {

    var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<Page>]
    var selectedIdx = 0
    @State var currentPage = 1

    init(_ views: [Page], selectedIdx: Int) {
        self.viewControllers = views.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
        self.currentPage = selectedIdx
        print("ReceivedIdx: \(selectedIdx)")
        print("Current page: \(currentPage)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        PageViewController(controllers: viewControllers, currentPage: $currentPage)
    }
}

//struct PageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
//    static var previews: some View {
//        PageView(features.map { FeatureCard(landmark: $0) })
//            .aspectRatio(3/2, contentMode: .fit)
//    }
//}
```

### PageViewController

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct PageViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var controllers: [UIViewController]
    @Binding var currentPage: Int

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll,
                                                      navigationOrientation: .horizontal)

        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        pageViewController.setViewControllers([controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController

        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewController) {
            self.parent = pageViewController
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            if index == 0 {
                return parent.controllers.last
            }

            return parent.controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            if index + 1 == parent.controllers.count {
                return parent.controllers.first
            }

            return parent.controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if completed,
                let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first,
            let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController)
            {
                parent.currentPage = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer From [this post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58137096/10158398). this morning!

In one word:

> SwiftUI doesn't allow you to change @State in the initializer but you can initialize it.

So in my case, remove the initial value on @State `currentPage` and set it directly using `State(initialValue:)` in your `init()`.

Remember to use `_` before `currentPage`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PageView<Page: View>: View {

    var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<Page>]
    @State var currentPage: Int

    init(_ views: [Page], selectedIdx: Int) {
        self.viewControllers = views.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
        _currentPage = State(initialValue: selectedIdx)
    }

    var body: some View {
        PageViewController(controllers: viewControllers, currentPage: $currentPage)
    }
}
```