# Selecting an existing item on an array or passing a new one to a .sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an array that contains the data that is displayed on a list. When the user hits "new", a sheet pops up to allow the user to enter a new item to the list.

I just added a swipe option to edit this item and I wanted to reuse the same sheet to edit the item's text. But I'm having problems understanding how to check whether a specific item was selected (by UUID?) to pass to the sheet, or it's a new item.

Code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

struct NoteItem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
    var date = Date()
    var dateText: String {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d yyyy, h:mm a"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    var tags: [String] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
    @State private var selectedItemId: UUID?
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var sheetIsShowing = false

    NavigationView {
        List(filteredNotes) { note in
             VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                 //....
                 // not relevant code
             }
             .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                 Button(action: {
                      selectedItemId = note.id
                      self.sheetIsShowing = true
                 } ) {
                     Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                 }
             }
        }
        .toolbar {
            // new item
            Button(action: {
                 self.sheetIsShowing = true
            }) {
                 Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsShowing) {
                if self.selectedItemId == NULL { // <-- this is giving me an error
                    let Note = NoteItem(id: UUID(), text: "New Note", date: Date(), tags: [])
                    SheetView(isVisible: self.$sheetIsShowing, note: Note)
                } else {
                    let index = data.notes.firstIndex(of: selectedItemId)
                    SheetView(isVisible: self.$sheetIsShowing, note: data.notes[index])
                }
            }

    }
}
```

My rationale was to check whether `self.selectedItemId == NULL` was null or not, if not then pass that element to the sheet to be edited, if yes, the as it as a new element.

What am I doing wrong? And if there is a standard way to pass information to the sheet based on whether there is an item select or not, could you show me?

Thanks!

Comment: You must use the sheet in the 2 places : one in foreach list the other for new. In this case you can inform the sheet it s is new or existing to be modified.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you. Are you telling me I need to code two different sheets? Or pass that it's a new item or an edit of an existing one?

Comment: Two .sheet modifiers : one after .wipe, second after .toolbar. The sheet then can be the same

Comment: even if it's the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176412/can-t-pass-data-correctly-to-modal-presentation-using-foreach-and-coredata-in-sw/61176759#61176759), you can do like this in your case:

```
struct SheetForNewAndEdit: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    // The selected row
    @State var selectedNote: NoteItem? = nil
    @State private var sheetNewNote = false
    // for test :
    @State private var filteredNotes: [NoteItem] = [
        NoteItem(id: UUID(), text: "111"),
        
        NoteItem(id: UUID(), text: "222")];
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(filteredNotes) { note in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    //....
                    // not relevant code
                    
                    Text(note.text)
                }
                .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                    Button(action: {
                        // the action select the note to display
                        selectedNote = note
                    } ) {
                        Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                    }
                }
            }
            // sheet is displayed depending on selected note
            .sheet(item: $selectedNote, content: {
                note in
                SheetView(note: note)
            })
            // moved tool bar one level (inside navigation view)
            .toolbar {
                // Toolbar item to have toolbar
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    ZStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            // change bool value
                            self.sheetNewNote.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetNewNote) {
                let Note = NoteItem(id: UUID(), text: "New Note", date: Date(), tags: [])
                SheetView(note: Note)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note : SheetView does not need any more a boolean, but you can add one if you orefer

Comment: Great, thank you. I need to figure out how to not create a new item each time you edit one, but this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses `nil`, not `null`, so the compiler is complaining when you are comparing selected items to `null`. However, you will have another issue. Your `selectedItemId` is optional, so you can't just use it in your else clause to make your `note`. You are better off using an `if let` to unwrap it.  Change it to:

```
    .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsShowing) {
        if let selectedItemId = selectedItemId,
            let index = data.notes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == selectedItemId }) {
            SheetView(isVisible: self.$sheetIsShowing, note: data.notes[index])

        } else {
            let note = NoteItem(id: UUID(), text: "New Note", date: Date(), tags: [])
            SheetView(isVisible: self.$sheetIsShowing, note: note)

        }
    }
```

edit:

I realized that you were attempting to use two optionals without unwrapping them, so I changed this to an if let to make sure both are safely unwrapped.

Comment: Thank you. I get the same error with nil: `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`.
If I remove the if, then it compiles without an issue

Comment: I was already editing my answer as I found another bug. Part of the problem is this is not a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can't see what you are seeing. The error you are seeing generally means there is a syntax error or logic error.

Comment: And I found a third error. then you use `let index = data.notes.firstIndex(of: selectedItemId)`, `index` will be an optional, so I included that in the `if let` to safely unwrap it.

Comment: Yeah, thank you I saw that. I winds down to `Cannot convert value of type 'UUID' to expected argument type 'NoteItem'` in `data.notes.firstIndex(of: selectedItemId)`

Comment: Try the edit. It needed to be a comparison. `$0` is an unnamed argument that represents an element in your `data.notes` array as it is iterated through.